# Angular pushing data to user node

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am building my first mobile application in Ionic and everything is
going well. I have created a user login where the user gets their own node in firebase once logged in. However, I want to save data to the
logged in user. At the moment the data is saving to its own node. My
method is below

```
this.diary = db.list('UID');//this is where I think I am going wrong?

handler: data=> {
                    this.diary.push({
                        country: data.a,
                        city: data.b,
                        month: data.c,
                        day: data.d,
                        time: data.e
                })
```

any help would be great, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `push()` on a database reference, Firebase created a new unique location under that reference.

It seems that you want to store the data under the user's UID, instead of under the new unique location. To do this, call `child(...)` instead of `push()`. E.g.

```
this.diary = db.list('UID');
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

handler: data=> {
                this.diary.ref.child(user.uid).set({
                    country: data.a,
                    city: data.b,
                    month: data.c,
                    day: data.d,
                    time: data.e
            })
```

But in this case it's probably easier if you bypass AngularFire for this operation and go straight to the JavaScript SDK:

```
db.child('UID').child(user.uid).set(...)
```

Comment: I have changed to this but I am getting the error 'child does not exist on type firebaselistobservable'

Comment: Hmm... indeed it doesn't. In that case it should be something like `this.diary.ref.child(...)`. But it's even easier if you just go straight to the database: db.child('UID').child(user.uid).set(...)`.